# custom arrangement of favorites in default (HTC) browser?

Tags: browser, bookmarks, 2.1-eclair

can I arrange my favorites in default HTC Desire (2.1) web browser the way I want? Not only by newest, mostly used, alphabetical?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, one solution is the Bookmark Sort & Backup app. Visit [here](http://happydroid.com/) from phone or search for "bookmark sort" on android market. (Pro version comes without ads.) Hope it helps.

**EDIT:** [Bookmark Sort & Backup Free](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.happydroid.bookmarks) and [Bookmark Manager Free](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.impulseapps.bookmarkmanagerfree) on appbrain.com.

Comment: [Bookmark Manager Free](http://impulseapps.com/bookmarkmanager/) is another alternative.

Comment: I used `Bookmark Manager Free` and it does great job. Thank you

Comment: Do these work for the standard Android 2.2 browser too?

Comment: Actually I just downloaded it and it works like a charm!