# Is it possible to change the name underneath the icons on the home pages?

Tags: 2.1-eclair, home-screen-shortcuts, home-screen

Just wondering: is it possible to change the name which is displayed underneath the icons on the home pages ?

I added some short cuts to internet pages on these pages, and they use way too long names . It would be nice if I could change them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>No, this won't work for shortcuts to apps.</s>  **EDIT2:** Turns out this part of the answer was wrong. Thanks Bryan and Drake for your answers.

Yes, it works for internet bookmarks. From your browser, select Menu > Bookmarks. Long-press the given bookmark and select Edit Bookmark; this will allow you to change its name. You may need to delete/re-add the shortcut to your home page for the change to take affect.

**EDIT1:**  Alternatively, if you use a bookmark manager app (like any of the ones mentioned [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1254/custom-arrangement-of-favorites-in-default-htc-browser/1258#1258)), you should be able to edit the bookmark directly from there.

Answer (score 3):

[LauncherPro](http://www.appbrain.com/app/launcherpro/com.fede.launcher) is a great Home Switcher app, personally is the best.

Between the different dozens of useful features it provides also the possibility to change the text of all home icons that are shortcuts to applications, to bookmarks, etc.

Answer (score 2):

[BetterCut](http://www.appbrain.com/app/bettercut/com.betterandroid.bettercut) will let you create shortcuts with custom icons/text.

Comment: Is BetterCut still maintained (as far as you know). Went to their website, but it has no obvious reference to the product any more ( I couldn't find an email address either ). Do you need OpenHome to use BetterCut ?

Comment: @Edelcom I'm not sure, I haven't used BetterCut. But there is a free alternative called AnyCut.  It is a little less feature complete.  Neither should require OpenHome